# SQL code can't see a certain table

Tags: sql

```
insert into airports(country_id)
select country_id 
from countries 
where countries.country_name =  flight_all.dep_country
```

This simple code can't compile because sql doesn't see flight_all table. how can I make it visible (without any extra 'from' keywords) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should google [**SQL JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

You probably want `DISTINCT` to avoid insert duplicated

```
insert into airports(country_id)
select distinct country_id 
from countries
join flight_all
  ON countries.country_name =  flight_all.dep_country
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `flight_all` isn't defined in your query.  You need to identify your tables in the `FROM` clause.  Using your current approach, it would look something like this:

```
select country_id 
from countries, flight_all
where countries.country_name = flight_all.dep_country
```

**However**, note that this syntax is considered fairly sloppy (and perhaps even deprecated depending on the RDBMS).  Instead, use a `JOIN` instead of a `WHERE` clause to perform your `JOIN` logic.  Something like this:

```
select country_id 
from countries
inner join flight_all
on countries.country_name = flight_all.dep_country
```

Comment: Dont recomend first version because is already consider obsolete. Note, by the way, that implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it